# 8085 microprocessor op-code statement faults

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

The problem statement is :

> Load a data byte A2H in memory location 8150H and 76H in the accumulator. Add the contents of the memory location to the contents of the accumulator.

The opcode statement that I used for execution of the problem in the 8085 micro processor based microcomputer kit, is :

- 3E:76:26:81:2E:50:36:A2:86:CF

which is :

- MVI A,76H
- MVI H,81H
- MVI L,50H
- MVI M,A2H
- ADD M
- RST 1

what's wrong in the problem statement? while examining the accumulator, after executing, it isn't showing the desired result.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific** problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I never worked with 8085, but from a brief google you will need a `#` in front of immediate operands. Such as `MVI M, #A2H` and the preceding ones. Operands without the `#` are usually treated as memory addresses. Even so, some assemblers require a `0` (or other mark) in front of a hex value to distinguish it from a *label*. For example is `A2H` a value or a label? The value `0A2H` is a value, as labels may not start with a numeric character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much a shot in the dark, but you could try this. Two alterations. Immediate values need a `#`, and hexadecimal values beginning with a letter need a `0` prefix to distinguish from labels.

```
MVI A,#76H
MVI H,#81H
MVI L,#50H
MVI M,#0A2H
ADD M
RST 1
```

Comment: Amazingly, this was accepted as the best answer *4 years* after posting it. Thank you!